# Ajax: link in ajax response is not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have tried all possible solutions suggested, but it is still not working for me.

I am using ajax call to a php page, say livesearch.php, from index page to get live search result.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $("#livesearch").on("click", "a.alert", function() {
                alert("here");
            });
        </script>   
        <script>
            function showResult(str) {
                if (str.length == 0) {
                    $("#livesearch").empty();
                    $("#livesearch").css('display', 'none');
                    return;
                }

                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "livesearch.php?q=" + str,
                    success: function(responseText) {
                        $("#livesearch").html(responseText);
                        $("#livesearch").css('display', 'block');
                        $("#livesearch").css('background', '#fff');
                    }
                });
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <input type="text" size="30" onkeyup="showResult(this.value)" onblur="showResult('')" placeholder="search here">
            <div id="livesearch" style="height:500px;width:900px;overflow-y:scroll;display:none;z-index:99999;"></div>
        </form>
        <div id="gentext" style="position:fixed;top:40px;z-index:-1;">This is just a dummy text to check if result div overshadow this line or not.</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

It works fine and list possible search. 
Now from search results, a user can click on a page to browse it - simple. As soon as one click's on the link, I want to catch that and do some processing. See below section in above code:

```
$("#livesearch").on("click", "a.alert", function() {
    alert("here");
});
```

To begin with, I am testing, if I am able to capture click on this link returned from ajax search or not - so alert("here"), but it is not working.

Please hep

Comment: Isn't it obvious you have to define the `$("#livesearch").on(....` *after* appending the link to the dom?

Comment: Can you please elaborate it for me. I am using .on (for live) to inform that something else is coming where event needs to be handled.

Comment: In otherwords that command goes after `$("#livesearch").html(responseText);` Added this as an answer.

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but still no result

Comment: what?.. so your AJAX works fine, and your alert works fine.. what are you trying to accomplish? do you want to alert the results of your Ajax, everytime the user clicks on #livesearch?

Comment: @CodeGodie - Ajax is getting results, link is there, user can click link, but I am not able to capture it. In simpler words, I am not getting the alert ("here") ever

Comment: @Ramesh have you tried the answer "developerwjk" gave you?

Comment: @CodeGodie - yes I did, still no luck. I am still not getting the alert

Answer (score 2):

Define the click method after appending the links:

```
success: function(responseText)
{
   $("#livesearch").html(responseText);
   $("#livesearch").css('display', 'block');
   $("#livesearch").css('background', '#fff');
   $("#livesearch").on("click", "a.alert", function() 
   {
      alert("here");
   });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, and let us know what the console returns:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "livesearch.php?q=" + str,
    success: function(responseText) {

       console.log(responseText); //CHECK YOUR CONSOLE 

       $("#livesearch").append(responseText);
       $("#livesearch").css('display', 'block');
       $("#livesearch").css('background', '#fff');
       $("#livesearch").find(".alert").click(function(e) {
           e.preventDefault();
           alert("here");
       });
    }
});
```

Another way to accomplish this is to build your anchor tag like this `<a href="" onclick="return myFunction()"></a>`, then create the JS function:

```
myFunction(){
    alert("here")
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Hitting this error: Uncaught ReferenceError: resposeText is not defined.

Comment: The problem probably lies in your PHP. provide your php

Comment: There was a type error in line console.log(resposeText).. Trying now

Comment: It is getting result. I can see <a class='alert' href=''>text</a> in console log. But clicking it is not working.

Comment: try `e.preventDefault();` I had a typo

Comment: I think the problem happens only if link is part of an ajax response. In your fiddle, it is in same JS

Comment: no, its working on my local machine with AJAX. Maybe I can try helping you remotely. Do you have Teamviewer?